# HTML and CSS - Vertical align divs

Tags: css, css-tables

I have a div on the left hand side, and text on the right hand side.  The text can be either 2 or 3 lines long, and I want the left hand div to be vertically centered to that text.  I've looked online and it seems that all the ways to do this without using tables are complicated.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Most suggestions seem to point to http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html which uses "CSS tables".  Are CSS tables the way to go? Is that really better than just using HTML tables?

Comment: FWIW, the link you reference doesn't work at all in Safari on the Mac. Other Mac-based browsers do fine with it, though.

Comment: @Robusto - Does http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/priklady/vertical-align-final-solution-en.html work? I just tried it on mac safari and it worked, however its a new macbook...

Comment: WSpines: I'm talking about the "example" that links from the link in your 2nd paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, CSS tables are better than HTML tables because they do not imply any semantic meaning but are explicitly used to describe presentation.

However, for your case CSS's `vertical-align` works. For example: http://jsbin.com/itoyo3/edit.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'll go with the CSS tables.  I tried vertical-align but it didn't work.  The div to the left is floated left, and so is the div to the right.

Comment: Perhaps you can put the two divs in a container and float the container? Then the simple `vertical-align` solution would work.

Comment: @Spines, I think for `display:table-cell` to work that element has to be nested within `display: table-row` element and *that* within a `display: table` element. Which kinda makes sense, you can't have a table-cell outside of a table: it'd be meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with absolute positioning;

Change your code to look like this:

`<div id="right-content"><div id="the-left-hand-div">whatever goes here</div><p>The content</p></div>`

Set your css up like this:

```
#right-content {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: /*the width of the the left div content plus any margin you want*/
}

#the-left-hand-div {
    position: absolute;
    left: /*negative width of the the-left-hand-div plus any margin you want*/
    top: /*height of #right-content - the-left-hand-div divided by 2 - this could be a negative value if the-left-hand-div is higher than the right-content*/
}
```