# CSS Vertical Align: Browser Quirks

Tags: css, layout, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394976/html-and-css-vertical-align-divs) about how to make vertical align with css, Sam's comments leads to this page: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/priklady/vertical-align-final-solution-en.html

The solution on the page uses display table css property, which is said not to work on ie6 and 7 by [Browser quirks encyclopedia](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html). However, [i6 renderer](http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/index.php) shows it correctly. Is the Browser quirks encyclopedia wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `display: table;` part doesn't work as expected in Internet Explorer 6 (and probably not in 7 either, if that's what QuirksMode says).  Using `display: table;` and similar in those browsers doesn't render divs in rows and columns, which is what it's supposed to do.  For this reason, the Browser Quirks Encyclopedia is correct to say that old versions of IE don't support this CSS feature.

**However** the specific vertical-align example that you linked to **does** work with IE6 (and I would assume IE7 as well).  It doesn't display perfectly (IE6 uses a different width than Chrome and IE 8), but aligning vertically works.  I just tested this in an XP virtual machine with IE 6.0.2900.2180.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Displaying perfectly on ie6 is something we gave up a while ago, but displaying marginally well is good enough for us.